# How do I enlarge and center a font icon in Angular Material Design?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I'm trying to center the play arrow in the middle of a fab speed dial, both the dial and the arrow show up, but no matter what I've tried (including using `<i>` and putting the classes directly on `md-icon`), I have been unable to get the icon to enlarge and be in the center of the fab dial.

```
<md-fab-speed-dial>
    <md-fab-trigger>
        <md-button aria-label="Play" class="md-fab md-warn" layout-align="center center">
            <md-icon
                    class="md-48"
                    layout-align="center center"
                    >play_arrow</md-icon>
        </md-button>
    </md-fab-trigger>
    <md-fab-actions>
    </md-fab-actions>
</md-fab-speed-dial>
```

Here are the versions I've installed with bower

```
{
    "name": "angular-material-starter",
    "description": "A starter project for AngularJS Material",
    "version": "0.0.2",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/material-start",
    "license": "MIT",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "angular": "^1.4.x",
      "angular-animate": "^1.4.x",
      "angular-aria": "^1.4.x",
      "angular-material": "^0.9.x",
      "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.x"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "angular-material": "~0.9.x"
    }
  }
```

These are 2 fabs coded the same way, but have different alignments.

[image: image of the 2 speed dial fabs]

I have tried fiddling with the css in developer tools directly and that helps, but I feel like that isn't supposed to be required. How can I make the icon size 48 and be in the center of the fab?

**Update:**

oddly I just got it centered it appears that that is at least partially a problem with the starter's `app.css` which I have deleted the entire contents of.

the `material-icons` class needs to be added to `md-icon` apparently.

```
<md-fab-speed-dial>
    <md-fab-trigger>
        <md-button aria-label="Play" class="md-fab md-warn">
            <md-icon class="material-icons md-48">play_arrow</md-icon>
        </md-button>
    </md-fab-trigger>
    <md-fab-actions>
    </md-fab-actions>
</md-fab-speed-dial>
```

Comment: This would appear to be a known issues with md-icon - it might be worth following these...

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2597
https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2630

Comment: oddly I just got it centered it appears that that is at least partially a problem with the starter's `app.css` which I have deleted the entire contents of

Comment: Hmm, angular material is constantly changing (icons going from  px to em and back to px) for example. Perhaps app.css has not kept up with changes...

Comment: yeah but, `md-48` should still apply that change, I would think. it seems like that isn't applying the rules it should, not sure why. I know manually changing the size works.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit this link to view the answer

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2597

in my case just add a class `set-icon-fab`

```
.set-icon-fab {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
   }
```

and I run